# script to restart process on Debian WSL

Tags: windows-10, bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have amule-daemon installed on Debian 11 WSL.
Process amuleweb crashes every now and then so I need to restart it.

I'm trying to automate this with the following bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ $(pgrep amuleweb) ]]; then
   echo "amuleweb is running..";
else
   echo "amuleweb is not running, restarting now..";
   amuleweb --amule-config-file=/home/debian/.aMule/amule.conf
fi
```

but no matter if amuleweb is running or not (I'm checking with "ps aux | grep amule"), the script always returns "amuleweb is running.."

This is an example with amuleweb stopped.

```
debian@CUSPIDE:~$ ./amuleweb.sh
amuleweb is running..
debian@CUSPIDE:~$ [[ $(pgrep amuleweb) ]]
debian@CUSPIDE:~$ echo $?
1
```

If I run the pgrep command directly from a terminal, it works, but within my script it always returns "0".

How do I fix it?
Thanks

Comment: You should just `if pgrep -a amuleweb` instead. After debugging, you can change it to `if pgrep amuleweb > /dev/null` if you want. Probably you need `-x`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking an educated guess here that the name of your script might include the string `amuleweb`.  If this is the case, then `pgrep` is finding the running script.  Best practice here would be to use the `pgrep -f` (or `-x`, as @TomYan pointed out in the comments) form to make sure you are matching on the desired executable.

You might also consider the user of a process manager for this type of scenario (restarting a failed service) rather than rolling your own.  While WSL now includes the ability to use Systemd, that would probably be overkill here unless you already have it enabled for other reasons.  Take a look at [Supervisord](http://supervisord.org) as a fairly lightweight, easy-to-configure process supervisor that can restart failed services.

Comment: Thanks, that was it, i.e. name of the script :)